# I need help using an if then elif statement for optional variable assignment

Tags: bash, scripts

I posted some time back an old MPV bash script i found on the net and i was trying to modify it. Well I'm still at it. The issue here is I'm trying to use an if then elif statement to assign either file="$f", file="$filename", or echo an error statement and exit if there are no files. file="$filename" and the echo/exit work. however file="$f" only loops the first file. the preceding for do loop finds all files as it loops through $dir, but it doesn't pass the new file name over to the rest of the script when the next loop starts.

"$f" is a file looped in a for do loop that most of the script is in. but it doesn't seem to affect file="$filename" in any way.

I've tried a case statement, but i couldn't get that working.
code:

```
#!/bin/bash -x



while getopts ":d:f:s:i:n:g:v:" opt; do
  case $opt in
d)
  declare -r  location="$OPTARG"
  ;;
f)
  declare -r filename="$OPTARG"
  ;;
s)
  declare -r startFrame="$OPTARG"
  ;;
i)
  declare -r intervalScreenshots="$OPTARG"
  ;;
n)
  declare -r numberScreenshots="$OPTARG"
  ;;
g) 
  declare -r videoHeight="$OPTARG"
  ;;
v)
  declare -r verbose="TRUE"
  ;;
\?)
  echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
  exit 1
  ;;
:)
  echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
  exit 1
  ;;
  esac
done

if [[ -z "$location" ]] ; then
 declare -r dir="."
else
   declare -r dir="$location"
 fi
for f in "$dir"/*.*

do

if [[ -z "$filename" ]] ; 

then

declare -r file="$f"

elif [[ -f "$filename" ]] ;

then

declare -r file="$filename"
else

echo "No Files Found"
exit

fi

mkdir "$(basename "$file" | cut -d "." -f1)"
#start mpv

mpv --pause --quiet --no-osc --no-audio --osd-level=0  --no-border --vo=opengl --framedrop=no --scaler-lut-size=8 --scale=spline36 --cscale=spline36 --opengl-fbo-format=rgb16 --linear-scaling --geometry="$videoHeight" --screenshot-template=%F_%ws --screenshot-format=png --screenshot-png-compression=5 --screenshot-directory="$(basename "$file" | cut -d "." -f1)" "$file" --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket  > /dev/null 2>&1 &


# Informations grabbing
#declare -r filename="$(basename "${file}" )"

 sleep 1

 declare -r lastFrame="$(echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "estimated-frame-count"]}' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d , -f1)" 

 sleep 1

 declare -r fpsVideo="$(echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "estimated-vf-fps"]}' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d , -f1)"


 sleep 1

# Declare interval for each screenshot
if [[ -z "$intervalScreenshots" ]] ; then
  declare diffFrame="$(awk "BEGIN {printf $lastFrame - $startFrame}")"
  declare intervalFrame="$(awk "BEGIN {printf $diffFrame / $numberScreenshots}")"

else
  declare -r intervalFrame="$intervalScreenshots"
fi

# Looping to take screenshots
declare currentFrame="$startFrame"
for i in $(seq 1 "$numberScreenshots") ; do

   declare currentTime="$(awk "BEGIN {printf $currentFrame / $fpsVideo}")"

  if [[ -n "$verbose" ]] ; then
    printf 'Filename: %s\n\n' "$filename"

    printf 'Current time: %.2f\n\n' "$currentTime"

    printf 'Last frame: %s\n' "$lastFrame"
    printf 'FPS: %s\n' "$fpsVideo"
    printf 'Interval: %s\n' "$intervalFrame"
    printf 'Screenshot: %02d\n\n\n' "$i"

 fi
  # Debug line



   echo '{ "command": ["set_property", "pause", true] }'    | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket

   sleep 1

   echo '{ "command": ["seek", '$currentTime', "absolute" ] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket

   sleep 1

   echo '{ "command": ["screenshot", "window"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket

   sleep 1



currentFrame="$(awk "BEGIN {printf $currentFrame+$intervalFrame}")"



done

echo '{ "command": ["quit"] }'  | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket

done
```

Comment: I don't really understand why you are using `declare -r` everywhere for what appear to be simple variable assignments - it certainly doesn't make any sense (at least, not to me) to declare a variable as `readonly` *inside* a loop (in particular, if `file` is readonly then `file="$f"` will only assign the *first* `f` from your `for f in "$dir"/*.*`)

Comment: In retrospect that's really obvious. Basically I had some issues with the math operations doing funky stuff when i had them using BC. I switched over to awk (after a lot of reading). I just used declare -r for constancy. Then I simply never went back and changed it. There's still a bit of code i need to clean up and some internal help stuff to rewrite as well.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short i failed to realize that declare -r made it so my variable wouldn't be changed in later loops. Thanks to steeldiver for pointing that our. There was really no point in making it read only in the first place. I just did it for consistency after using for debugging some old (long gone) BC math functions.